# How to query a sorted list of products based on user size?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to add features to the search page, so endpoint `/api/products` will return a paginated list based on sizes of user. Currently, this endpoint only filters products by URL parameters.

Products have category and size. User has personal size parameters: `top_size`, `shoe_size` and `pant_size`. How to sort the list to first show items that match the user's size? I need a conditional query depending on category, because for different categories I need different values to filter `top_size`, `shoe_size` and `pant_size`.

```
async getProducts(req, res, next) {
    let {page, brand, category, title} = req.query;

    const {size_interests} = await UserModel.findById(req.session.userId);
    const {short_size, pant_size, shoes_size} = size_interests;
    ...
    const query = {};
    ...
    // way to a query for the dynamic size
    // for some categories it's short_size
    // for some categories it's pant_size
    // for some categories it's shoes_size

    // Also I shouldn't hide other non-matching items, they should be sorted to end of the list

    const products =
    (await Product.find(query)
      .skip((page - 1) * limit)
      .limit(limit)
      .populate("images")
      .sort(sort)) || [];
  }
```

How to do this with Mongoose? I tried just single size filter, but it drops other products from results.